# How to set the nagios plugin path

Tags: ubuntu, nagios

When I am checking nagios setting.

I bumped into this error.

```
$ sudo /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios -v /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg

Nagios Core 4.4.5
Copyright (c) 2009-present Nagios Core Development Team and Community Contributors
Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Ethan Galstad
Last Modified: 2019-08-20
License: GPL

Website: https://www.nagios.org
Reading configuration data...
   Read main config file okay...
Error: check_period '24x7                                                                                                          |' for service 'check_snmp' on host 'localhost' not found!
Error: Could not register service (config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/localhost.cfg', starting on line 226)
   Error processing object config files!
```

OK , I guess it is because system can't find `check_snmp`

I found `check_snmp` here.

```
$ sudo find / -name check_snmp
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp
```

On the other hands, `check_http` exists in these directory.

```
sudo find / -name check_http
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_http
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_http
/opt/nagios-plugins-2.2.1/plugins/check_http
```

So, I guess `Nagios` plugin path is set only for `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/`??

If so, how can I solve this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds more likely to me that localhost has a service definition check_snmp in `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/localhost.cfg` that refers to a timeperiod named:

```
24x7                                                                                                          |
```

(with lots of trailing spaces and a pipe character) as a copy/paste typo for the *actual* timeperiod `24x7`.

Comment: oooops thank you. you are write I made type(put some blank and `|`) in configuration file...

Comment: Configuration file works well, but this error happens. `(No output on stdout) stderr: execvp(/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_snmp, ...) failed. errno is 2: No such file or directory`

Comment: Might be worth a new question. Sounds like it could be a mismatch with what you're expecting (`/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_snmp`)

Comment: This might be another problem. I will google around for now. and might make new article. thank you very much.